# Is Yod a vowel in hebrew?

Tags: hebrew

If hebrews d'ont use vowels in writing why  letter yod is pronnounce y like in english yes.Semitics have vowels in their alphabet or no?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matres_lectionis

Answer (score 2):

In English, the letter Y sometimes functions as a vowel, and sometimes as a consonant.  For instance in the word "spy", it functions as a vowel, being pronounced like the vowel "i" in the first personal pronoun "I".  But in the word "yellow", it functions as a consonant, being pronounced like the letter "j" in "fjord".

In Hebrew, the letter י (yod) is defined as a consonant, but sometimes stands for a vowel (just as ה and ו can also sometimes stand for vowels) - though only in specific situations.  See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mater_lectionis).